# How to pass a record from list view to a show view

Tags: react-admin

I have a list of records that user can view each of them in a new page, which is a show view, by a show button. In the new page, there will be other list views that use some fields of the record.

Can I pass the record from my list view to show view so that I don't need to request again by filtering it? In case there is no other way that I have to make another getList request, where should I put the filter options?

the page be like:

App.tsx

```
<Resource name="record-detail" show={RecordDetail} />
```

RecordList.tsx

```
<List>
<Datagrid>
 <ShowButton resource="record-detail" />
 ...
</Datagrid>
</List>
```

RecordDetail.tsx:

```
const renderAnotherListByRecord = (record:any) => {
 return <AnotherList resource="another-list" filter={{id: record.id}} />
};

<Show>
<SimpleShowLayout>(showing the record)</SimpleShowLayout>
<FunctionField render={renderAnotherListByRecord}/>
</Show>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to pass a record from a page to another page, but I have a work-around.

Put the record to `localStorage`, in dataProvider just retrieve the stored record for the show view.

In RecordList.tsx, use a `FunctionField` to render the show button.

```
const renderShowButton = (record:any) => {
 const onClick = () => {localStorage.setItem("current_record", JSON.strigify(record));}
 return <ShowButton resource="record-detail" onClick={onClick} />
}
```

Customize a new dataProvider.

```
export const newDataProvider = {
    getOne: (resource:any, params:any) => {
        const record = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("current_record") || "");

        return new Promise((resolve:any) => {
            const data = {data: record}
            resolve(data);
        });
    },
};

export default newDataProvider ;
```